# Square Brackets at the beginning of postman Json Array

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have an api that expects a Json Array body like so:

```
{
"rrr":"123456788",
"channel":"BRANCH",
"amount":5500.00,
"transactiondate":"12/04/2017",
"debitdate":"12/04/2017",
"bank":"050",
"branch":"48794389",
"serviceTypeId":"346346342",
"dateRequested":"12/04/2017",
"orderRef":"",
"payerName":"Amira Oluwatobi ",
"payerPhoneNumber":"+23443846434",
"payerEmail":"seunfapo1@yahoo.com",
"agencyCode": "834873463",
"revenueCode": "49384983",
"customFieldData": [
{
"DESCRIPTION": "GPRR",
"COLVAL": "48374387"
}
]
}
```

It works as expected on postman, but my supervisor wants a Json array with angle brackets at the beginning and end like so:

```
[
 {
    "rrr":"123456788",
    "channel":"BRANCH",
    "amount":5500.00,
    "transactiondate":"12/04/2017",
    "debitdate":"12/04/2017",
    "bank":"050",
    "branch":"48794389",
    "serviceTypeId":"346346342",
    "dateRequested":"12/04/2017",
    "orderRef":"",
    "payerName":"Amira Oluwatobi ",
    "payerPhoneNumber":"+23443846434",
    "payerEmail":"seunfapo1@yahoo.com",
    "agencyCode": "834873463",
    "revenueCode": "49384983",
    "customFieldData": [
    {
    "DESCRIPTION": "GPRR",
    "COLVAL": "48374387"
    }
    ]
    }
]
```

This does not work in postman, it sends an empty json array object. is there a way to make it work like this? or does the angle bracket even matter at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your should check the expected type at your API, it's likely not matching your json.